# Is it possible to define multpile methods with the same mapping but different paramters in Spring/REST?

Tags: java, rest

In Spring/REST, isn´t it possible to define two API methods with the same mapping, but different parameters?

```
  @RepositoryRestController
  @RequestMapping("/api/dailyEntries")
  public class DailyEntryController implements 
  ResourceProcessor<Resource<DailyEntry>> {

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<DailyEntry>> getDailyEntriesFromCustomerId(@RequestParam() Long customerId) {
      return dailyEntryService.getDailyEntriesFromCustomerId(customerId);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<DailyEntry>> getDailyEntriesFromEmployeeId(@RequestParam() Long employeeId) {
      return dailyEntryService.getDailyEntriesFromEmployeeId(employeeId);
    }
  }
```

Im getting an error which states that theres already a bean method mapped, which is caused by the same `@GetMapping` i tried using for both. The reason i didn´t want to make it one method with optional parameters is because that would require some additional logic in the methods body. I would like to only allow sending either `customerId` or `employeeId`, but not both, which i cant do when im forced to sum it up in one method and make both paramters optional.

Is there a way to either split it up in two methods like i tried above(i dont really want to add different mapping) or sum everything up in one method and only allow one of the both optional parameters to be sent?

Comment: Just a guess and I can't check it now, but I'd guess you need to specify the request parameter's name, like this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param#specifying-the-request-parameter-name.

Comment: That didn´t work for me, but something similar worked. I had to specify a **params** parameter like this: `@GetMapping(params = "customerId")` and `@GetMapping(params = "employeeId")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The can be achieved by specifying params on the `@GetMapping annotation` and specifying the requestParam value you want to capture.

Like below.

```
@GetMapping(params = "customerId")
public ResponseEntity<List<DailyEntry>> getDailyEntriesFromCustomerId(@RequestParam(value = "customerId") Long customerId) {
  return dailyEntryService.getDailyEntriesFromCustomerId(customerId);
}

@GetMapping(params = "employeeId")
public ResponseEntity<List<DailyEntry>> getDailyEntriesFromEmployeeId(@RequestParam(value = "employeeId")  Long employeeId) {
  return dailyEntryService.getDailyEntriesFromEmployeeId(employeeId);
}
```